# F#: Derivative Function

Tags: f#, derivative

I'm trying to figure out how to get this function to work. I'm very inept with F#, so explanations are appreciated,

```
let deriv (f:(float->float), dx: float) = 
    fun f:(float -> float) * dx:float -> x:float -> float
let (f, dx, x) = ((f(x + dx) - f(x))/dx)
```

Am I using `f:(float->float)` wrong?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In stead of trying to fix your problems I will explain it from the ground up.

The symbolic derivative is a function that takes a function and returns a new function. However you are trying to calculate the [numeric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) that returns a value given a function, a value, and a delta.

First we will give the function a name: `deriv`
and it needs three parameters:
1. A function that takes in a float and returns a float: `(f : float -> float)`
2. A value of where the derivative is to be evaluated: `(x0 : float)`
3. A delta: `(dx : float)`

You had two of the three parameters in your example, but were missing `x0`.

It should also return a float.

So the signature is

```
deriv (f : (float -> float)) (x0 : float) (dx : float) : float
```

Now to calculate the numeric derivative.
I won't explain this, but just reference [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)

For this example we'll use a simple function that has derivative, `x^2`.

Here is the code in F#

```
// val deriv : f:(float -> float) -> x0:float -> dx:float -> float
let deriv (f : (float -> float)) (x0 : float) (dx : float) : float =
    let (x1 : float) = x0 - dx
    let (x2 : float) = x0 + dx
    let (y1 : float) = f x1
    let (y2 : float) = f x2
    let (result : float) = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    result

// val f : x:float -> float
let f x = x**2.0
```

and a quick test show it works correctly.

```
// val it : float = 2.0
deriv f 1.0 0.000005
```

For a more thorough test of a range of values.

Using [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) install [FSharp.Charting](http://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/)

In F# Interactive

```
#I "..\packages"
#load "FSharp.Charting.0.90.13\FSharp.Charting.fsx"
open FSharp.Charting

let xs1 = [ for x in (double)(-3.10) .. 0.05 .. 3.10 do yield x]
let ys1 = xs1 |> List.map f
let values1 = List.zip xs1 ys1
Chart.Line(values1)
    .WithXAxis(Min=(-4.0), Max=4.0, MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=2.0, IntervalOffset = 1.0, LineWidth = 2))
    .WithYAxis(Min=(0.0), Max=10.0, MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=2.0, IntervalOffset = 1.0, LineWidth = 2))
```

[image]

which can also be confirmed using Wolfram Alpha: [x^2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2)

A simpler example:

```
// val d : x:float -> float
let d x = deriv f x 0.00000005

let xs2 = [ for x in (double)(-3.10) .. 0.05 .. 3.10 do yield x]
let ys2 = xs2 |> List.map d
let values2 = List.zip xs2 ys2
Chart.Line(values2)
    .WithXAxis(Min=(-4.0), Max=4.0, MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=2.0, IntervalOffset = 1.0, LineWidth = 2))
    .WithYAxis(Min=(-6.0), Max=6.0, MajorTickMark = ChartTypes.TickMark(Interval=2.0, IntervalOffset = 1.0, LineWidth = 2))
```

[image]

which can also be confirmed using Wolfram Alpha: [d/dx x^2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20x%5E2)